# Simulate outliers and nonlinear data to test one-class classifiers

Tags: r, classification

I'm looking for a R code / package which simulate nonlinear data with outliers in order to test some one-class classifier algorithms.

I've found this code which create a banana-shaped dataset. It is pretty good because my real data looks like an hyperbola in 2d. 
But I need a dataset where all the outliers are labeled, so that I can print a confusion matrix and evaluate the performances of my models.
It doesn't necessarily have to look like this. The most important thing is the nonlinearity.

Thanks in advance.

```
banana=function(A,B,C1,C2,N,keep=10,init=10)
{
R=init*keep+N*keep
x1=x2=0
bimat=matrix(double(2*N),ncol=2)
for (r in 1:R) {
    x1=rnorm(1,mean=(B*x2+C1)/(A*(x2^2)+1),sd=sqrt(1/(A*(x2^2)+1)))
    x2=rnorm(1,mean=(B*x2+C2)/(A*(x1^2)+1),sd=sqrt(1/(A*(x1^2)+1)))
    if (r>init*keep && r%%keep==0) {
        mkeep=r/keep; bimat[mkeep-init,]=c(x1,x2)
    }
}

return(bimat)
}

# usage
set.seed(66)
nvar2=2
A=0.5; B=0; C1=C2=3
y2=banana(A=A,B=B,C1=C1,C2=C2,1000)
```

Comment: Can you just sort the data so that the last few rows are outliers? And the classifier can give you the predicted class, Take that vector and your results vector, compare the results and you have your confusion matrix.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by sorting data? They are in 2d, a high value in one of the two dimensions doesnt imply that it is an outlier.

Comment: What kind of outliers are you looking for?  You could just add points like x=3, y=3  or do you want points that approximately fit your distribution but are just a little bit too far away.

Comment: Points that approximately fit the distribution but are just a little bit too far. It would be amazing if I could set that "little bit too far" and test different scenarios.

Comment: Re-reading your question,  it seems to me that you are not tied to this distribution.   Is that correct?  If there was a different way of generating similar points that also made it easy to have controllable outliers,  would that work for you?

Comment: Yes, it would work for me. The data have to be just nonlinear.

Comment: @G5W Hi, eventually did you come up with an idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The idea is to generate data where y is a non-linear function of x plus some noise. When you want outliers,  use the same generation process except force the noise to be "large".  You can tune what "large means.

```
NonLinear = function(n) {
    x = rnorm(n, 5, 1)
    y = (x-3)^3/10 + rnorm(n,0,1)
    data.frame(x,y)
}
plot(NL)

NL_Outliers = function(n, Lower, Upper) {
    x = rnorm(n, 5, 0.8)
    y = (x-3)^3/10 + 
        sample(c(-1,1), 10, replace=TRUE) * runif(n, Lower, Upper)
    data.frame(x,y)
}

NL = NonLinear(200)
plot(NL, ylim=c(-4,10))
NLO = NL_Outliers(10, 3.2, 4.5)
points(NLO, pch=20, col="red")
```

[image: Nonlinear data with tuned outliers]

Comment: Thank you very much. If I prefered having a less linear shape and I changed the relationship between X and Y, would I set the noise generated by rnorm(n,0,1) in a different way? I mean, how do I set the choice of the noise? And the costant in the X/Y dependence?

Comment: I will add some detail to the answer.

Comment: That would be great. I've tryed to change the functional relationship with a hyperbola, but the output looks like a random cloud with no shape. I suppose it is due to the mean and sd of rnorm.